# How to get JSON from URL

Tags: android, json

I am getting Json file from url and want to show data from json file node by node and then to save the data into DATABASE. I am using the following code but not working please help me in finding error.I have mentioned the internet permission in manifest file. I am also adding my LOGCAT. thanks.

My Main Activity:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   String url="maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+31.5279024+","+74.3495554;
   JSONArray user = null;
   private static final String TAG_USER = "results";
   private static final String TAG_address = "address_components" ;
   private static final String TAG_addressLName = "long_name";
   private static final String TAG_addressSName=  "short_name" ;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // Creating new JSON Parser
    JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

   // Getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    try {
      // Getting JSON Array
      user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
      JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);
      // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
      String id = c.getString(TAG_address );
      String name = c.getString(TAG_addressLName );
      String email = c.getString( TAG_addressSName);
      //Importing TextView
      final TextView uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);
      final TextView name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name1);
      final TextView email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
      //Set JSON Data in TextView
      uid.setText(id);
      name1.setText(name);
      email1.setText(email);
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }  
}
```

My JSON Class

package com.parsep.parse;

```
   public class JsonParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JsonParser (){

    }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url )
    {
        try
        {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient= new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);
        //  httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return jObj;
    }
    }
```

My LOGCAT:

```
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity               
   ComponentInfo{com.parsep.parse/com.parsep.parse.MainActivity}:               java.lang.IllegalStateException:       
    Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null,               path=maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at com.parsep.parse.JsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(JsonParser.java:40)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at        com.parsep.parse.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   at               android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
   11-05 14:45:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(533):   ... 11 more
   11-05 14:45:30.010: I/dalvikvm(533): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
   11-05 14:45:30.049: I/dalvikvm(533): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
   11-05 14:45:30.350: I/dalvikvm(533): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
   11-05 14:45:30.360: I/dalvikvm(533): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: Malaika, I think you need to write your url: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+31.5279024+","+74.3495554;

Comment: @pratt i already tried that

Comment: Malaika, but your error clearly shows that host must not be null, that means you entering url invalid.

Comment: ok i have changed this but still not working

Comment: go with my answer below Malaika, I have post my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace following lines with your code.It may be helpful

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   String url="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+31.5279024+","+74.3495554";
   JSONArray user = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to add "http://" to your url to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this way:

```
new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute(); // write this in onCreate(); method.

     public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";

            // set your json string url here
            String yourJsonStringUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+31.5279024+","+74.3495554;;

            // contacts JSONArray
            JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {}

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

                try {

                    // instantiate our json parser
                    JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

                    // get json string from url
                    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);
                    //Below parsing is just for your reference, do your task here.
                    // get the array of users
                    dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("Users");

                    // loop through all users
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String firstname = c.getString("firstname");
                        String lastname = c.getString("lastname");
                        String username = c.getString("username");

                        // show the values in our logcat
                        Log.e(TAG, "firstname: " + firstname
                                + ", lastname: " + lastname
                                + ", username: " + username);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have tried this but still not showing anything i am updating my question again after applying async task with logcat

Comment: @MalaikaKhan okay, can you send me your code to me?

Comment: @MalaikaKhan pratikdasa@gmail.com

Comment: @MalaikaKhan okay, let me check it okay, dnt wry.

Comment: @MalaikaKhan What you want get exactly from that url? lat-long or all address data?

Comment: @MalaikaKhan you only wants to convert single latitude and longitude to its address/

Comment: yeah exactly and actually i am getting lat long through GPS and I am making a report that shows LAt LOng with Address

Comment: @MalaikaKhan if you want to convert single lat-long in address then not need to process this long stuff dear, you can directly get it using lat-long using Reverse Geocoding.

Comment: actually I have tried this but not working I think I am doing something wrong but dont know what actually the error is

Comment: have a look
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668335/how-to-save-google-coordinates-name-in-database-geocoder-is-not-working

Comment: @MalaikaKhan see my new answer, it will help you.

Comment: I am getting different person Lat Long and than converting it to address

Comment: @MalaikaKhan so no problem na, when you get lat-long just call that method get address data and save it wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only address list from lat-long then use reverse geocoding.

Call below method like this way and get data.

```
Address address=getAddressListFromLatLong(YOUR LATITUDE, YOUR LONGITUDE);
String country=address.getCountryName();
String address1=address.getAddressLine(1);
Strin address2=address.getAddressLine(2);
String postalCode=address.getPostalCode();

public static List<Address> getAddressListFromLatLong(double lat, double lng) {
        geocoder = new Geocoder(YOUR ACTIVITY.this);

        List<Address> list = null;
        try {
            list = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 10); //10 is for results, you can use 1 if you want 1 result only.
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```